# android - resuming from last visited page in my app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have login page (activity) which is my first activity (landing page) of the app.
Only after user gives correct username and password, the app allow you go to other pages to work with.

Now my question is, now the user is at the fourth page and he is working on it, And he minimize the app and use other app like messaging etc..
so when he come back to click my app icon again, my app starts from the first landing page, which is the login page, 
how can I make my app to resume from the fourth page?

Android 4.4.4, Kit Kat,  Samsung

Regards,
Nay TK

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" add this in android manifest in your parent activity(mainActivity) in your case login activity

Comment: That is because whenever user taps on the app icon in application drawer, the OS always launches the LAUNCHER activity (LoginActivity in your case). If the user resumes the app from recents menu than OS will resume it from the last state if the app was maintained in memory. In the former case, you'll have to manage that in your code.

Answer (score 2):

**Add this in android manifest of loginActivity**,

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

more on **android:launchMode**

An instruction on how the activity should be launched. There are four modes that work in conjunction with activity flags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_* constants) in Intent objects to determine what should happen when the activity is called upon to handle an intent. They are:

"standard"

"singleTop"

"singleTask"

"singleInstance"

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

go through [official link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

You can make your fourth activity as your launch activity.
In the Resume of your Activity, you check if the user is logged in. If not, you start your Login activity.